# How can one append a div exactly in the position where the mouse is over? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to leave a colored div trail without generating divs when the page loads. I want them to be appended when the mouse is over the parent div and position them where the mouse is within it.

**EDIT**: I think I need to be more precise so I posted the code that I want to rewrite. I want it to do the same thing without generating the divs that become colored on mouseover when the page loads but to create a colored div when the mouse is over $(".container") at the current position of the mouse.

THANKS!

Mention: the script generates lots of divs - it might take a while for the page to load.

```js
 $(document).ready( function() {

  var csize = $(".container").width() * $(".container").height();
  var space = $(window).width() * $(window).height();


  while ( csize * $(".container").length < space) {
   $("#space").append("<div class='container'></div>");
  };

  $(document).on("mousemove", function() { 
   window.color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  }); 
  
  $(".container").on("mouseover", function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "#" + window.color);
  
  });  

  



  
});
```

```css
#space{
 width: auto;
 height: auto;

}

.container {
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 border: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head> 
 <title> JqPractice</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="sv2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="space"> 
 <div class="container">

 </div>
</div>
</body>


<footer>


</footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#parent").on({
    mousemove: function (e) {
        var wrapper = $(this);
        var parentOffset = wrapper.offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left + wrapper.scrollLeft();
        var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top + wrapper.scrollTop();

        wrapper.find('.randomTrail:visible').remove();
        wrapper.append($('<div class="randomTrail"/>').css({
            left: relX,
            top: relY
        }));
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.randomTrail:visible').remove();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wWEqP/57/)

Ref:

1. [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)
2. [.scrollLeft()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)
3. [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)
4. [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
5. [e.pageX](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [e.pageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/)
6. [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
7. [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)
8. [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)
9. [Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)
10. [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `mousemoves()` to get the event data and coordinate like below

```
$( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
    msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
    console.log(msg);
});
```

and you will need a div with css `{position:absolute; width:10px; height:10px; background-color:yellow; left: event.pageX; top:event.pageY}` something like this will do

For more info checkout [official doc](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) from `jQuery`